# How to clear program/service from Windows firewall rule with netsh

Tags: windows-firewall, netsh

I want to use netsh.exe to modify an existing Windows firewall rule, to remove the "Programs" and "Services" part of the rule. In other words, I want to set it to "All programs that meet the specified conditions", and "Apply to all programs and services". I can't find a way.

This is what I tried:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=MyRule new program=
>
> Error: The application contains invalid characters or length

And:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=MyRule new program=""
>
> Error: The application contains invalid characters or length

And:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=MyRule new program=''
>
> Creates a program path that is literally ***''***

And:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=MyRule new program=any
>
> Creates a program path that is literally ***any***

EDIT: I'm on Windows 7 so the PowerShell Set-NetFirewallRule cmdlet is not an option.